# Procedure to import a site to Acquia Dev Desktop

Tags: migrations, acquia-dev-desktop

So, I'm looking for a painless procedure to import a site into Acquia's Dev Destkop on Windows

Theoretically, the procedure should be

1. Install clean drupal site (clean db and codebase)
2. Create Database and user for site to be migrated with phpmyadmin
3. Copy sites folder to new drupal root
4. Configure settings.php file to match new server environment.
5. Run Update.php script

The problem is I get a `PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'psr_admin'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in drupal_get_installed_schema_version() (line 155 of C:\Users\Nick\Sites\devdesktop\psr_final\includes\install.inc).`

This is the procedure I've followed on a number of installations, and I am wondering what I am doing wrong, or which aspect of the configuration is incorrect. I've even gone into phpmyadmin and re-created the database user and password to make sure that all the settings are correct. So, can someone tell me what I did wrong, or point me to the correct way to import a site into Acquia's dev desktop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dev desktop hides the settings file on local sites, so it's a little difficult to see what the settings actually are.

Looks like you're on windows. Hopefully you can find the directory your local settings are stored in by looking at where they are on my mac:

```
~/.acquia/DevDesktop/DrupalSettings/
```

The local settings file name has the pattern:

```
cld_prod_<site_name>_<dev_test_prod>_default.inc
```

Don't change this file. But you can see if it's accessing the psr_admin user you set up. By default my settings file shows the user 'drupaluser' with '' (an empty string) for a pw.